# Two errorClasses in jQuery Validator?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I know that you can specify the class name to use for errors, but is it possible to specify a second class name if the error happens on a specific element?
I have a form with inputs and the errors are all aligned to be directly under the input (like so:)

[image]
but I have a checkbox further on the page and the current errorClass ends up looking like this:
[image]
I want to create a different style for that checkbox so it will align properly.

Comment: There was an oversight in my original answer.  It's been corrected and I added a working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to have the plugin apply more than one "error" class, other than using its various built-in callback functions ([`highlight`, `unhighlight`, etc.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)) to apply/remove additional classes.  This can quickly get messy and verbose.

But there's really no need to complicate how the plugin spits out the default `.error` class, when you have CSS.

Just specifically target the error message (`label`) for the checkbox (with the `.error` class) using CSS...

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/gfLR9/

**CSS**:

```
label[for='myfieldname'].error {

}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myfieldname" />
```

---

**Clarification**:  The above target `label[for='myfieldname'].error` will not interfere with any other additional `label` elements you may have for this same input. Because it's very specifically targeting only those `label` elements also with `class="error"`.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/PcxKS/

Comment: It worked perfectly! I can't believe I didn't think of that before instead of making the solution so complicated. I just needed fresh eyes I guess.